# Sharing ansible variable between plays

Tags: amazon-ec2, ansible

This is a follow up to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/961845/setting-dynamic-inventory-hostnames-from-ansible).

I have a play that provisions a bunch of EC2 instances. By necessity, the `hosts` value is `localhost` (because when it's run there are no hosts), and the play assembles a new host list called `ec2hosts`, and generates a host ip to hostname map *because this is the first and only time that information is made available*, and saves it using `set_fact`. This hosts list is then the subject of a follow-up play. The problem is that I need to use the `hostname_map` dict created during the provisioning play in the second play, and I can't see how to do this.

Here's the first play:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: False

  tasks:
    - name: Provision a set of instances
      ec2:
        key_name: marcus
        instance_type: t2.micro
        image: "{{ ami_id }}"
        wait: true
        exact_count: "{{ server_count }}"
        count_tag:
          Tutorial: "{{ tutorial_name }}"
        instance_tags:
          Tutorial: "{{ tutorial_name }}"
        groups: ['SSH', 'Web']
      register: ec2

    - name: Add all instance public IPs to host group
      add_host:
        hostname: "{{ item.public_ip }}"
        groups: ec2hosts
      loop: "{{ ec2.instances }}"

    - name: Build an IP to hostname map
      set_fact:
        hostname_map: "{{ hostname_map | combine({item.0.public_ip: (item.1 + '.' + tutorial_domain)}) }}"
      loop: "{{ ec2.instances|zip(hostnames)|list }}"

    - name: Debug hostname_map
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostname_map }}"
```

At the end of this, `hostname_map` contains a map like:

```
{
    "18.184.109.70": "host1.example.com", 
    "18.196.135.59": "host2.example.com"
}
```

From reading the ansible docs on variable scope, it says that variables defined in a play are not available outside that play unless it's being applied to the same set of hosts. That's not possible in this case, so I need to use a var with global scope, and from what I've read, `set_fact` is the appropriate way to do that. So I created an empty variable in `/group_vars/all`, so that the variable is accessible to all plays:

```
hostname_map: {}
```

The next play connects to each newly-created instance (using the host list we created dynamically) and sets its hostname from the inside:

```
- hosts: ec2hosts
  gather_facts: yes
  tasks:
    - name: Debug hostname_map
      debug:
        msg: "{{ hostname_map }}"
    - name: Set hostnames
      hostname:
        name: "{{ hostname_map[ansible_host] }}"
```

However, this fails because `hostname_map` is empty

```
TASK [Debug hostname_map]
ok: [18.184.109.70] => {
    "msg": {}
}
ok: [18.196.135.59] => {
    "msg": {}
}
```

so I get this error:

> fatal: [18.184.109.70]: FAILED! => {"msg": "The task includes an option with an undefined variable. The error was: 'dict object' has no attribute u'18.184.109.70'

Curiously I get the same debug output and error *even when I don't define the variable globally*.

Other articles I've read all suggest that the values should be enumerated explicitly in `vars`, but I can't do that because the data is dynamic and unknown until runtime. Similarly, I can't provide it using `extra_vars` on a command line for the same reason.

How can I make this variable available within the second play? I'd like to avoid clunky solutions like writing a local file out and then reading it back in!

I'm also open to suggestions for doing this a completely different way, where "this" is: create an arbitrary number of EC2 instances and assign them hostnames taken from a static list.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A value you set with `set_fact` will be available between different plays. Keep in mind that set_fact are **set for a specific host**.  Your first play is run against **localhost** so the fact is part of the localhosts variables. So it the following play you should be able to access it with a task like this.

```
- debug:
    var: hostvars['localhost']['hostmap']
```

Answer (score 4):

You could use *dummy host* which will store all the variables you want to share with a help of [add_host](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/add_host_module.html). Then just access your variables with [hostvars](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/devel/user_guide/playbooks_vars_facts.html#information-about-ansible-magic-variables)

```
- hosts: "18.184.109.70"
  user: ubuntu
  tasks:
    - name: set a variable
      set_fact:
        shared_variable: "Some value"
    - name: add variables to dummy host
      add_host:
        name: "variable_holder"
        shared_variable:  "{{ shared_variable }}"

- hosts: "18.196.135.59"
  user: ubuntu
  vars:
    shared_variable: "{{ hostvars['variable_holder']['shared_variable'] }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg: "{{ shared_variable }}"
```

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how you define play. If you have multiple plays with a single ansible run it works. However does not work with multiple sequential plays. What I mean it doesn't work when you run ansible-playbook playbook1.yml, and afterwards ansible-playbook playbook2.yml